# Finding eigenvalues of a large ( >1000 x 1000) matrix accurately

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I'm doing a spectral method-based eigenvalue problem where I create a matrix, A, of size (nr+1)*(nz+1)*(2nf+1) where nr,nz,nf are integers, composed of a diagonal of (2nf+1) submatrices of size (nr+1)*(nz+1). I then take the eigenvalue of this matrix with respect to the right hand side matrix, B, which is composed of two diagonal sets of submatrices that are symmetric about i = j.

My problem is that because the matrices are so large (>1000x1000) it is difficult to quickly troubleshoot issues. I use both the direct eigenvalue function and a method using singular value decomposition, which both yield different (and both incorrect) results.

I've tried changing the precision and increased the nodal points (integers nr, nz, and nf) but it does not change the accuracy issue.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

--------how to generate the matrices-------------

NOTE: The matrix, A, here is called 'lhs' and the matrix, B, is called 'rhs' in the below code.

```
nodesZ = 6;
nodesR = 10;
nodesF = 5;
om = 100.0;
R = 42.32;
H = 7.98;
m = 1;
Ra = 900;
Pr = 0.08;
As = 1;
As2 = As^2;

DZOperator = 
  Table[If[i == j, 
     If[i == 0, -(2*nodesZ^2 + 1)/6, 
      If[i == nodesZ, (2*nodesZ^2 + 1)/6, 
       Cos[i*Pi/nodesZ]/(2*(1 - (Cos[i*Pi/nodesZ])^2))]], 0], {j, 0, 
     nodesZ}, {i, 0, nodesZ}] + 
   Table[If[i == j, 0, 
     If[Or[i == 0, i == nodesZ], 2, 1]/
       If[Or[j == 0, j == nodesZ], 2, 
        1]*(-1)^(i + j)/(Cos[j*Pi/nodesZ] - Cos[i*Pi/nodesZ])], {i, 0,
      nodesZ}, {j, 0, nodesZ}];

D2ZOperator = MatrixPower[DZOperator, 2];
DROperator = 
  Table[If[i == j, 
     If[i == 0, -(2*nodesR^2 + 1)/6, 
      If[i == nodesR, (2*nodesR^2 + 1)/6, 
       Cos[i*Pi/nodesR]/(2*(1 - (Cos[i*Pi/nodesR])^2))]], 0], {j, 0, 
     nodesR}, {i, 0, nodesR}] + 
   Table[If[i == j, 0, 
     If[Or[i == 0, i == nodesR], 2, 1]/
       If[Or[j == 0, j == nodesR], 2, 
        1]*(-1)^(i + j)/(Cos[j*Pi/nodesR] - Cos[i*Pi/nodesR])], {i, 0,
      nodesR}, {j, 0, nodesR}];

D2ROperator = MatrixPower[DROperator, 2];
T = Table[(-1)^n*N[Cos[p*n*Pi/nodesR], 20], {p, 0, nodesR}, {n, 0, 
    nodesR}];
gaussT = Table[(-1)^n*N[Cos[((2*p + 1)*n*Pi)/(2 nodesR + 1)], 20], {p,
     0, nodesR}, {n, 0, nodesR}];
invT = Inverse[gaussT];
dhat = Dot[Inverse[T], DROperator, T];
dg = Reverse[Map[Reverse, Dot[gaussT, dhat, invT]]];
Zeros = Table[
   0, {i, 1, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)*(2 nodesF + 1)}, {j, 
    1, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)*(2 nodesF + 1)}];
Ones = IdentityMatrix[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
OnesR = IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1];
OnesZ = IdentityMatrix[nodesZ + 1];

gr = Reverse[
   Table[-N[Cos[(2 l + 1)*Pi/(2 nodesR + 1)], 20], {l, 0, nodesR, 1}]];
d2g = MatrixPower[dg, 2];
erdamQ = gr[[nodesR + 1]];
erdamR = Table[
   erdamQ/(erdamQ - 1)*gr[[l]] + 1/(1 - erdamQ), {l, 1, nodesR + 1, 
    1}];
grinv = Table[
    1/(gr[[nodesR + 1]]/(gr[[nodesR + 1]] - 1)*gr[[l]] + 
       1/(1 - gr[[nodesR + 1]])), {l, 1, nodesR + 1, 1}]*
   IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1];
c = (gr[[nodesR + 1]] - 1)/gr[[nodesR + 1]];
qDr = c*dg;
qD2r = c^2*d2g;
c1 = 1/c;

Lap = 1/As2*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, Dot[grinv, qDr]] - 
   m^2/As2*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, grinv^2] + 
   1/As2*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, qD2r] + 
   4*KroneckerProduct[D2ZOperator, OnesR];
op1 = 1/As2*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, grinv^2];
op2 = 2*m*op1;
op3 = 1/As*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, qDr];
op4 = 1/As*m*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, grinv];
op5 = 1/As*KroneckerProduct[OnesZ, grinv];
Lz = 2*KroneckerProduct[DZOperator, OnesR];

boundaryzero = 
  Table[0, {i, 1, nodesR + 1}, {j, 1, (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)}];

boundarydzbottom = 
  KroneckerProduct[DZOperator, OnesR][[1 ;; nodesR + 1, 
   1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]];
boundarydztop = 
  KroneckerProduct[DZOperator, OnesR][[
   nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
   1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]];

boundarydr = (Dot[erdamR*IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1], qDr] + 
     IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1])[[1]];


lhs = Table[
   0, {i, 1, 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)*(2 nodesF + 1)}, {j, 1, 
    5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)*(2 nodesF + 1)}];
k = 0;
Do[
  lhsmini = 
   Table[0, {i, 1, 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)}, {j, 1, 
     5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)}];

  m11 = Lap - op1 - I*n*om*IdentityMatrix[(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)];
  m11[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundarydzbottom;
  m11[[(nodesZ)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   boundarydztop;
  Do[
   s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
   s[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = 1;
   m11[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = m11;

  m12 = op2;
  m12[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m12[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m12[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[
    1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     2*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = m12;

  m14 = -op3;
  m14[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m14[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m14[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] =
    m14;

  m21 = op2;
  m21[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m21[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m21[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ, 1}];

  lhsmini[[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     2 (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   m21;

  m22 = Lap - op1 - I*n*om*IdentityMatrix[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  m22[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundarydzbottom;
  m22[[(nodesZ)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   boundarydztop;
  Do[
   s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
   s[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (i + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = boundarydr;
   m22[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     2 (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     2 (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = m22;

  m24 = -op4;
  m24[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m24[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m24[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     2 (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] =
    m24;

  m33 = Lap - I*n*om*IdentityMatrix[(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)];
  m33[[1 ;; nodesR + 1, 1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1];
  m33[[nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1];
  m33[[nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    1 ;; nodesZ*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   Table[0, {i, 1, nodesR + 1}, {j, 1, nodesZ*(nodesR + 1), 1}];
  m33[[1 ;; nodesR + 1, nodesR + 2 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   Table[0, {i, 1, nodesR + 1}, {j, 1, nodesZ*(nodesR + 1), 1}];
  Do[
   s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
   s[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (i + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = qDr[[1]];
   m33[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[
    2*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1) + 1 ;; 3*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1), 
    2*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1) + 1 ;; 3*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] =
    m33;

  m34 = -Lz;
  m34[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m34[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m34[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[
    2*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1) + 1 ;; 3*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1), 
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] =
    m34;

  m35 = Ra*IdentityMatrix[(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)];
  m35[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m35[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m35[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[
    2*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1) + 1 ;; 3*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1), 
    4*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1) + 1 ;; 5*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] =
    m35;

  m41 = op5 + op3;

  lhsmini[[
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = m41;

  m42 = -op4;

  lhsmini[[
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     2*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = m42;

  m43 = Lz;

  lhsmini[[
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    2*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] =
    m43;

  m53 = IdentityMatrix[(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)];
  m53[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
  m53[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   boundaryzero;
  s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  Do[
   m53[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[
    4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    2*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] =
    m53;

  m55 = Lap - I*n*om*Pr*IdentityMatrix[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
  m55[[1 ;; nodesR + 1, 1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1];
  m55[[nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   IdentityMatrix[nodesR + 1];
  m55[[nodesZ*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    1 ;; nodesZ*(nodesR + 1)]] = 
   Table[0, {i, 1, nodesR + 1}, {j, 1, nodesZ*(nodesR + 1), 1}];
  m55[[1 ;; nodesR + 1, nodesR + 2 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
   Table[0, {i, 1, nodesR + 1}, {j, 1, nodesZ*(nodesR + 1), 1}];
  Do[
   s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
   s[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; (i + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = dg[[1]];
   m55[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
   {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

  lhsmini[[
    4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] =
    m55;

  lhs[[5*k*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     5*(k + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
    5*k*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
     5*(k + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)]] = lhsmini;

  k = k + 1;,
  {n, -nodesF, nodesF, 1}];

rhs = Table[
   0, {i, 1, 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)*(2 nodesF + 2)}, {j, 1, 
    5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)*(2 nodesF + 2)}];

rhsmini = 
  Table[0, {i, 1, 5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)}, {j, 1, 
    5*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)}];

tcouple = -0.5*Ra*IdentityMatrix[(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
tcouple[[1 ;; nodesR + 1]] = boundaryzero;
tcouple[[(nodesR + 1)*nodesZ + 1 ;; (nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
  boundaryzero;
s = Table[0, (nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1)];
Do[
  tcouple[[i*(nodesR + 1) + 1]] = s;,
  {i, 1, nodesZ - 1, 1}];

rhsmini[[2*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 
    3*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1), 
   4*(nodesZ + 1)*(nodesR + 1) + 1 ;; 5*(nodesR + 1)*(nodesZ + 1)]] = 
  tcouple;

base = Table[
   If[Or[i == j + 2, i == j - 2], 1, 0], {i, 1, 2 nodesF + 1}, {j, 1, 
    2 nodesF + 1}];

rhs = KroneckerProduct[base, rhsmini];

eigs = Eigenvalues[{lhs, rhs}];
```

Comment: Hard to tell you anything useful if you don't give us a way to generate your matrices.

Comment: @J.M. I have added the code. You can see at the end is where the eigenvalue function is used. It spits out values but they are incorrect.

Comment: Doing `srhs = SparseArray[rhs]` it shows only 900 nonzero elements out of your 4235 x 4235 matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @MikeY , that's correct. The rhs matrix is much more sparse than the lhs matrix.

Comment: First of all, a matrix of size 1000 is not that big. Second, SVD is slower, no need to go through all the methods. They are all accurate for a sensible input. Most probably you a have a bug in the generation of matrices A and B. Try to debug them for much smaller dimensions.

Comment: Hi @yarchik, thanks for the input. I've found that in certain situations (other strongly related spectral methods problems) the SVD method will provide the correct eigenvalues while using the direct eigenvalue command will not. It is slower, you are correct. Also, I have debugged the small form of the matrix -- the problem is the eigenvalues of the smaller matrix corresponds to a lower spectral accuracy and so the eigenvalues are even more inaccurate. Nevertheless thank you and I will look further into a smaller dimensioned matrix.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. It makes sense to do SVD if B is almost singular. In this way you can discard a large number of vanishingly small singular values of B.

Comment: @yarchik however it may very well be a convergence issue. this is after all a 3D problem (r, z, and frequency space) and so it is difficult to discern whether just cranking up the number of nodes in each direction will improve the results. In previous 2D problems (z and frequency space) it would be possible to use something like 20 nodes for each, but the calculation time becomes tremendous with the third dimension.